# Performance between Python and Java drivers with OrientDB

Tags: java, python, performance, orientdb

I want to develop a project that need a noSQL database. After searching a lot, I chose OrientDB. I want to make an API Rest that can connect to OrientDB.

Firstly, I wanted to use Flask to develop but I don't know if it's better to use Java native driver between Python binary driver to connect with database.

Anyone have results of performance between these drivers?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK on *remote* connection (with a standalone OrientDB server) performance would be the same. 
The great advantage of using the Java native driver is the option to go embedded. If your deployment scenario allows it, you can avoid the standalone server and use OrientDB embedded into your Java application, avoiding network overhead.